# Inserting an image after an image remove any new lines in between

Tags: bug, images

Inserting an image after an image remove any new lines in between. Example:

[image]

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks!

Comment: @Servy I prefer to leave some empty spaces in case I want to insert some text in between.

Comment: @Franck if you agree it's dupe, you can insta-close it by clicking the blue button on top.